# how can I add multi columns into a table in on sql?

Tags: mysql

how can I add multi columns into a table in one sql?

this sql bellow is wrong , how to fix?

```
alter table jy_products add column 
`products_new_type`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 
`products_image_host`  tinyint(1) NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
`tpl_key`  varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT 'p1' ,
`rushorder`  tinyint(2) NOT NULL ,
`products_viewed`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`likes`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`comments`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`wishlists`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`shares`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`lookbooks`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`products_popular`  float(11,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0 ,
`status_off_date`  datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: Please mention what you get error?

Comment: You're just missing the comma at the end of the `products_new_type` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alter table jy_products  
add column `products_new_type`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
add column `products_image_host`  tinyint(1) NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
add column `tpl_key`  varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT 'p1' ,
add column `rushorder`  tinyint(2) NOT NULL ,
add column `products_viewed`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `likes`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `comments`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `wishlists`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `shares`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `lookbooks`  int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
add column `products_popular`  float(11,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0 ,
add column `status_off_date`  datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```